# Detect when UITableViewCell did load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to be able to detect when my custom `UITableViewCell` has been loaded on screen, so that I can programmatically do stuff to the view inside it. The only code I could get working was implementing `layoutSubviews()` inside the custom `UITableViewCell`, but this is bad practice because `layoutSubviews()` is called more than one time. Also, putting my code in `awakeFromNib()` doesn't work because I need to call a delegate property, which hasn't been set at that point. How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried to override init on custom cell class?

Comment: using `var delegate: MyProtocol { didSet { updateUI() } }` would help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two different ways you could do it.

In your `UITableViewDelegate` you can implement the delegate method that is called when a cell is about to be displayed.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Update the cell
}
```

Or in your `UITableViewCell` subclass you could implement `didMoveToSuperView`.

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    if superview != nil {
        // Update the cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep used `willDisplayCell`! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks!! DidMoveToSuperView didn't work for me but willDisplayCell works great!!

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious place IMHO would be in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, just after having dequeued an instance and done the relevant init there, just add a call to a custom method of your custom cell.

Comment: That would not work since the cell is not yet in the view hierarchy. For example, `setFirstResponder` can misbehave.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use the functions below to track the tableViewCell:-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
// return n ( n = number of rows required )
// If n > 0, the function below will get called n times
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
//Create views, labels, buttons whatever you want and wherever you want.
//Add them to the cell by using cell.addSubview("Your view/label")
return cell
}
```