# correctly passing data selected from UICollectionViewCell inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, delegates, uicollectionviewcell

From my main view controller, how to intercept and send to next view controller the item selected via tapping a UICollectionViewCell of a collection view inside a tableViewCell?

my main controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    private let kCellId = "myTableCell"
    var paymentMethods: [Item] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTable.delegate = self
        myTable.dataSource = self

        paymentMethods.append(Item(name: "item 1", image: nil))
        paymentMethods.append(Item(name: "item 2", image: nil))
        paymentMethods.append(Item(name: "item 3", image: nil))
        paymentMethods.append(Item(name: "item 4", image: nil))
        paymentMethods.append(Item(name: "item 5", image: nil))
        paymentMethods.append(Item(name: "item 6", image: nil))

    }


}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.kCellId, for: indexPath) as? MyTableCell {
            cell.backgroundColor = .purple
            cell.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = .green
            cell.arrayInCell = self.paymentMethods
            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }


}
```

my cell:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    let kCellId = "myCollViewCellId"
    var arrayInCell: [Item] = []

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        print("count: ", arrayInCell.count) //this is zero but array is used
        if arrayInCell.count > 5 {
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.bounds.width/5.5, height: self.bounds.height)
        } else {
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.bounds.width/5, height: self.bounds.height)
        }

        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout


    }

}


extension MyTableCell: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(arrayInCell[indexPath.row].name ?? "error")
    }
}

extension MyTableCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayInCell.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.kCellId, for: indexPath) as? MyCollectionCell {
            cell.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
            cell.collectionCellLabel.text = arrayInCell[indexPath.row].name
            cell.collectionCellLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            return cell
        }

        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }


}
```

Comment: can you refine the question with the actual problem and code related to it, this is too much code and i think reading delegates would help

Comment: I'll try to refine, and remove a bit of code but the issue is right  thi one. from my main view controller, how to intercept and send to next view controller the selection of a UICollectionViewCell of a collection view  inside a tableViewCell?

Comment: your issue is passing the data ? or getting the data from that cell in the first place ?

Comment: passing data, in second instance I'd like to know why thi code works but in the cell array is empty

Comment: then why would we care about where the data from ? the question is simply you have data need to be passed to X place if i am not wrong, update your question so we can help you better

Comment: updated, done my best to avoid unnecessary code, and changed question. think my starting delegation settings are necessary to understand my actual situation. hope it helps

Comment: Probably this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559352/detect-when-uitableviewcell-did-load) is what you are looking for

Comment: how could this solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution by myself, post here in case someone could need it in the future.

created this :

```
protocol CanGetItemFromCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func getItem(item: Item)
}
```

in myTableCell:

```
var delegateForInternalTap: CanGetItemFromCollectionViewCellDelegate?
```

and:

```
extension MyTableCell: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        print(arrayInCell[indexPath.row].name ?? "error")
        delegateForInternalTap?.getItem(item: arrayInCell[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

in the ViewController / cellForRow I set the delegate for the cell:

```
cell.delegateForInternalTap = self
```

and:

```
extension ViewController: CanGetItemFromCollectionViewCellDelegate {

    func getItem(item: Item) {
```

//do whatever you need with the item, maybe pass to some other controller via segue etc.
            print("ok", item.name ?? "error")

```
    }
}
```